# Can't build node.js app on heroku-- "App not compatible with buildpack", even after buildpack set

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I have a node.js app in a git repo that looks like this:

```
/docs
/server
.gitignore
```

The actual node app is in the '`server`' folder, but both it and the docs are in the git repo seen above.

I went through heroku's instructions for creating an app, and have the heroku cli installed on my laptop.

I went into the `server` folder of my repo and ran `heroku create` and made sure there was a new remote for heroku afterward-- there was. I also made sure to run `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs` and it did so successfully.  (I can see that in my heroku dashboard.)

But when I try git push heroku master I get the error in my post title.

Just for fun, I deleted my app on heroku and this time ran `heroku create` from the root folder, and not the `server` one.  I also ran `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs` again.  I double-checked the new heroku app name and remote and tried to push again.  Unfortunately I got the same "App not compatible with buildpack" message.

Is all this because my git repo's root folder doesn't have a package.json file?  Is there a way I can tell heroku, 'hey, look in the server folder for package.json when you're building'?